# PHP Captcha - Session always empty

Tags: php, session, captcha

Im trying to add a captcha to my registration form. The image is rendering just fine except the session variable is always empty, so it doesn't work at all..

I am using the following class : http://www.ejeliot.com/pages/php-captcha

According to the documentation i had to make a php file with the following content:

```
<?php
require('classes/PhpCaptcha.php');
$aFonts = array('fonts/VeraBd.ttf', 'fonts/VeraIt.ttf', 'fonts/Vera.ttf');
$oVisualCaptcha = new PhpCaptcha($aFonts, 200, 60);
$oVisualCaptcha->SetBackgroundImages('captchaimgbg.jpg');
$oVisualCaptcha->Create();
?>
```

And include this as an image.

Now ive looked into the Create(); function, and in this function another function named GenerateCode(); is called, which is responsible for generating the letters and putting it into a session variable.

The code is as follow:

```
      function GenerateCode() {
     // reset code
     $this->sCode = '';

     // loop through and generate the code letter by letter
     for ($i = 0; $i < $this->iNumChars; $i++) {
        if (count($this->aCharSet) > 0) {
           // select random character and add to code string
           $this->sCode .= $this->aCharSet[array_rand($this->aCharSet)];
        } else {
           // select random character and add to code string
           $this->sCode .= chr(rand(65, 90));
        }
     }

     // save code in session variable
     if ($this->bCaseInsensitive) {
        $_SESSION[CAPTCHA_SESSION_ID] = strtoupper($this->sCode);
     } else {
        $_SESSION[CAPTCHA_SESSION_ID] = $this->sCode;
     }
  }
```

The CAPTCHA_SESSION_ID is defined at the top of the class file.
In my index i have session_start(); , i double checked this and that is not the problem.

No matter what i try, $_SESSION is always empty, even if i add $_SESSION['bla'] = 'bla' manually in the create(); function, it doesn't show up.

Does anyone have an idea what is causing this, or what i am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: have you done a dump of the variables you are putting into the session? Are they empty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php

session_start();
require('classes/PhpCaptcha.php');
$aFonts = array('fonts/VeraBd.ttf', 'fonts/VeraIt.ttf', 'fonts/Vera.ttf');
$oVisualCaptcha = new PhpCaptcha($aFonts, 200, 60);
$oVisualCaptcha->SetBackgroundImages('captchaimgbg.jpg');
$oVisualCaptcha->Create();

?>
```

You need to start the session with `session_start()` at the TOP of the code on all the pages that access/set `$_SESSION` variables.

Comment: He said: `In my index i have session_start()`

Comment: This seems to fix it, however all my pages are loaded via my index.php file (its kinda mvc'ish), and in the index the sessions are started, could you explain me why i have to start them again? Thanks for your fast reply tho!

Comment: @RyanNaddy, yeah in the index.php file, but not the image file. It has to be in ALL the pages that access/set $_SESSION vars.

Comment: You shouldn't have to. To me it sounds like you are not loading the file through your index file, or before you start your session.

Comment: @DavidEricsson Most likely because the function being called *before* you call `session_start`, or maybe it is destroyed before it is called too. You shouldn't have to call it twice, but doing so has no negative effect...

Comment: You are correct, i include this file as an image in my view file, and thereby not directly from the index .. i feel kinda dumb  -.- thanks for the answers guys!

Comment: @cryptic ahh, I forgot I was looking at an image file :) For every request from a client to the server you need a session start. So one for php files, php generated image, php generated JS, php generated CSS, etc. each one would need it's own `session_start`.

Comment: **Side Note:** I would also recommend NOT putting it into the file directly, but use a file that you can include. In the file you would put things such as: your session_start, db connections, static vars, api connections, etc. This should be a file that can be included in any php file without breaking the file, so no HTML, CSS, just PHP that "sets up" the page information.

Comment: @RyanNaddy, the image file only contains 6 lines of code, so including a file with just `session_start()` would not be reasonable in this case, however for other files site-wide it would.

Comment: @cryptic, that isn't what I mean. Writing session start in 100 files becomes redundant, and is very bad programming practice. It's like writing code that could be a function everywhere, why write 8 lines of code in 10 files when you could put them into a function and call it using 1 line of code. Putting things into one file that is used in many different places is always better than putting the same thing into many files. It could reduce your code by 50% or more.

Comment: @RyanNaddy, I was agreeing with you, just saying not to do it for the image file as it only has 6 lines of code. No need to include a global file to start session which may have other unnecessary things like db connect, etc. For other pages yes go ahead, as they will need access to those items. `include 'globals.php';` takes just as much space as `session_start();` in the image file.

Comment: @RyanNaddy You've gone so far. It's also a bad practice to use non-encapsulated `session_start()` and related session function in a global scope. The methods like, `Session::start()`, `Session::set()`, `Session::exists()` `....` should be used instead. The one file, like, `bootstrap.php` should do all basic things, like, again, `session_start()`

Comment: @cryptic Just one thing to note: It's better to use an autoloader (implemented via SPL internally ) rather than include and global containers. Say, you only include a `Autoloader` class and then "attach" a required class, like, `Autoloader::attach(\Core\Session.php)`